# Testing protected view - handling PermissionDenied response

Tags: django, testing, pytest

I'm trying to test a protected view. Unauthenticated users are redirect to login page. When I run the test, it raises `django.cose.exceptions.PermissionDenied` which is normal but how could I write it without getting a failure and how can I test if the redirection is correct?

Here is what I've done.

```py
class TestProtectedRegistrationListView:
    """
    Verify registration views are protected from unauthenticated access.
    """

    def test_access_url(
        self, user: settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, request_factory: RequestFactory
    ):
        view = RegistrationListView.as_view()
        request = request_factory.get("/admin_staff/registrations")
        request.user = user
        resp = view(request)
        assert resp == PermissionDenied
```

Comment: Maybe try `with pytest.raises(PermissionDenied)` and inside the `with` block test if redirection is correct?

Comment: Much more better! But every assertion I put inside the ```with``` block passes the test. For example: ```assert response.status_code``` is correct whatever the code is ```404``` or ```200```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for whom interested (rightly suggested by @wencakisa):

```py
def test_authenticated_non_staff(self, rf):
    req = rf.get(reverse("dashboard.staff:lang-create"))
    user = UserFactory()
    assert False is user.is_staff
    req.user = user

    with pytest.raises(PermissionDenied):
        views.LangCreateView.as_view()(req)
```

For memories and to answer my own *stupid* comment, testing the response `status_code` doesn't make any sense since we raised the excepted exception.